# How can I display a menu with dropdown based on options stored in database using NodeJS and EJS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have this table in Oracle SQL:

| ID | DESCRIPTION | IS_DROPDOWN | PARENT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dashboard | N |  |
| 2 | Orders | N |  |
| 3 | Customers | N |  |
| 4 | Options | N |  |
| 5 | Dropdown Item | Y | 3 |

I'm doing a project in Node JS and Express JS.

The table's name is SIDEBAR_MENU and are listed in the app.get in the app.js file:

```
    app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const sql = `SELECT ID, DESCRIPTION, IS_DROPDOWN, PARENT_ID FROM SIDEBAR_MENU ORDER BY ID`;
    
      try {
        const menuItems = await runQuery(sql);
        const loggedIn = req.session.loggedIn || false; // Use session.loggedIn if available, otherwise default to false
        res.render('index', { menuItems, loggedIn });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
      }
    });
```

My index.ejs is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Page App</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <%- include('partials/header') %>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div id="sidebar" class="col-md-3">
            <ul>
              <% menuItems.forEach(function(item) { %>
                <li><a class="sidebar-link" href="#" data-id="<%= item[0] %>"><%= item[1] %></a></li>
              <% }); %>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div id="content" class="col-md-9">
            <h1>Welcome to my app!</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
<%- include('partials/footer') %>    
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          // Listen for clicks on the sidebar links
          $('.sidebar-link').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            
            // Send an AJAX request to retrieve the content
            $.get('/content/' + id, function(data) {
              $('#content').html(data);
            });
          });
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to display the DESCRIPTION column which has IS_DROPDOWN = 'Y' as dropdown below the description of the PARENT_ID. Example:
In the table, the item 5 (Dropdown Item) should be displayed below the item 3 (Customers).